# Using ipywidgets to show certain data from dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, ipywidgets

I'm trying to create a slider that gives values from 0 to 100 and then it shows data from dataframe column that has ages from 0 to 100. I can't get the for loop to work. It just gives me errors like:

```
TraitError: The 'value' trait of an IntSlider instance must be an int, but a value of <function slider at 0x0000020D0F3A8828> <class 'function'> was specified.
```

Here's my code:

```
vaesto = pd.read_csv('X:/Ezter/Ezter/Data/vaestorakenne.csv', encoding='latin-1')
vaesto = vaesto.rename(columns={'Ikä':'ika'})

def slider(z):
    for i in range(i, z,len(vaesto['ika'])):
        vaesto.head(5)
widgets.IntSlider(slider, z='10')
```

And the data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WYvdJgqNk-MlRwvE7aDPp2U3Uow6FpMh/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You can only create an `IntSlider` with an integer value (in your case you tried to pass a function) e.g.

`my_slider = widgets.IntSlider(10)`

When you want to make that widget call another function as it changes, you might need the `my_slider.observe` method.

```py
my_slider = widgets.IntSlider(10)

def print_n(widget):
    n = widget
    print(n)
    
my_slider.observe(print_n, names='value')
display(my_slider)
```

Comment: This doesn't print anything in my jupyter notebook, am I missing something?

Comment: Just call `my_slider` in a new cell or add `display(my_slider)` to see.

Comment: This is what I did:
`my_slider = widgets.IntSlider(10)

def print_n(widget):
    for i in range(i, names,len(vaesto['ika'])):
        vaesto.head(5)
    
my_slider.observe(print_n, names='value')
my_slider()`

It gives me error 'IntSlider' object is not callable

Comment: Don't call your slider (`my_slider()`), it's not a function! Just do `display(my_slider)`.

Comment: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'e' referenced before assignment`

Comes up. I tried to change the index, but doesn't work.